# How to remove the file path from python debug console

Tags: python, debugging, terminal, vscode-code-runner

I'm using **code runner** extension on vscode to run python file and i to remove the path that appear when i run the code, Please help me.
[Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNE0m.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "python": "python3 $fileName"
},
```

Under your settings.json (hit `ctrl + shift + p` and type in settings.json), I have this added and it doesn't completely eliminate any output, but it's drastically reduced. You could also do `"python": "$pythonPath $fullFileName"` for a longer output, but you'll save yourself trouble if your Python path ever changes.

Examples can be found under their `Configuration` section: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner